# addEventListener in onclick firing onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to get a  with an onclick function to fire only when clicked. But I'm noticing after it's clicked and then on page load, the function is firing again.

Once I click 'Previous', the page goes to '/test1' for a second, then instantly loads '/test'. Am I not using this eventListener correctly?

**Note:** '/test1' and '/test2' are in one react project and '/test' is in another. I cannot use history.push for this scenario.

Header.js

```
<div id="header-link">
    <strong id="header-copy"></strong>
</div>
```

Entry.js

```
function getLink(currentPage, history) {
    if(currentPage.name === 'test1') {
        document.getElementById("header-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.pathname = '/test'
        });
        document.getElementById("header-copy").innerHTML = 'Back';
    }
    if (currentPage.name === 'test2') {
        document.getElementById("header-link").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        history.push('/test1') 
        });
        document.getElementById("header-copy").innerHTML = 'Previous';
    }
}
```

Comment: As I can see, `getLink` looking correct. Probably problem is somewhere outside this function (I'm not familiar with react so don't know how exactly `history.push` works)

Comment: The issue here appears to be that you keep adding event handlers. Just add one at page load and move all the logic into it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use addEventListener when onClick is enough.

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        if (window.location.href.endsWith("/test")) {
          history.push("/");
        } else {
          window.location.pathname = "/test";
          //history.push("/test");
        }
      }}
    >
      Click me
    </div>
  );
};
```

But if you insists on using addEventListener you need to [remove them](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/event-listeners-in-react-components).

Comment: I cannot use onclick in this component since this is coming from server side, not all info is there.

I also cannot use history.push('/')
Note: '/test1' and '/test2' are in one react project and '/test' is in another. I cannot use history.push for this scenario.